# Regex to find labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex

I'm trying to find all labels with an id and text, but my regex doesn't seem to work:

With the following regex:

```
<asp:[a-z]+.*? ID="(?<id>.*?)".*? Text="(?<text>.*?)".*?/>
```

and the following sample text:

```
<asp:Label ID="SomeID" Text="SomeText" />
<asp:Label Text="SomeText" />
<asp:Label ID="SomeID" />
<asp:Label ID="SomeOtherID" Text="Some Other Text" />
```

I get the following matches:

```
   1. "<asp:Label ID="SomeID" Text="SomeText" />" has 2 groups:
         1. "SomeID"
         2. "SomeText"
   2. "<asp:Label Text="SomeText" /> <asp:Label ID="SomeID" /> <asp:Label ID="SomeOtherID" Text="Some Other Text" />" has 2 groups:
         1. "SomeID"
         2. "Some Other Text"
```

The first one is obviously correct, but I'm not sure why #2 shows up.

And the following regex only finds the first label ("SomeID") but not the fourth one ("SomeOtherID"):

```
<asp:[a-z]+ (?!.*<[a-z]).*? ID="(?<id>.*?)".*? Text="(?<text>.*?)".*?/>
```

Comment: There's a well-worded explanation here! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why are you searching your code within your app? Surely there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe he's not searching his code within his app but rather within his editor? There are IDEs with regex support around...

Comment: I'm trying to find a list of all the phrases that need to be translated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `.*`s in your expression with `[^>]*`, to avoid crossing HTML tag boundaries. The problem is that the `.*?` in the middle of your expression matches `/> <asp:Label ID="SomeOtherID"`.

Perhaps something like this:

```
<asp:[a-z]+\s*ID="(?<id>[^"]*)"\s*Text="(?<text>[^"]*)"[^/]*/>
```

Comment: Just as an additional help, look for the ">>>> <<<<":
<asp:[a-z]+.*? ID="(?<id>.*?)">>>>.*?<<<< Text="(?<text>.*?)".*?/>